# c++ qt API works with Excel 2010 but not with ecxel 2013

Tags: c++, excel, qt, api, excel-2013

I have got a problem with API QT C++ to Excel. 
From QT I open an Excel Workbook, add 3 Tabs, name those 3 Tabs, Fill values into all Tabs, save the workbook with a new name (Save As).

My code works perfectly with Excel 2010. But when I run the programm (using Excel 2013) it crashes. Does anybody have any idea as to why that is?

Excel opens, shows 3 tabs (unnamed) and then crashes. 
It seems That the Programm stops before executing this line

```
QAxObject *sheet1 = sheets->querySubObject( "Item( int )", 1 );
```

My code :

```
    QAxObject* excel = new QAxObject( "Excel.Application", 0 );
    excel->dynamicCall("SetVisible(bool)",true);
    QAxObject *workbooks = excel->querySubObject( "Workbooks" );
    QAxObject *workbook = workbooks->querySubObject("Add()");
    QAxObject *sheets = workbook->querySubObject( "Worksheets" );

    QAxObject *sheet1 = sheets->querySubObject( "Item( int )", 1 );
    sheet1->dynamicCall("SetName(const QString&)", QVariant("Basics"));
    QAxObject *sheet2 = sheets->querySubObject( "Item( int )", 2 );
    sheet2->dynamicCall("SetName(const QString&)", QVariant("Name2"));
    QAxObject *sheet3 = sheets->querySubObject( "Item( int )", 3 );
    sheet3->dynamicCall("SetName(const QString&)", QVariant("Name3"));

    //... fill excel tabs...
```

Can anybody help me please ?

Thank you

itelly

Comment: Does anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I found my mistake:

in Excel 2010, when you open a new workbook there are **3 Tabs** included.  If you open Excel 2013 therer is only **1 Tab**

So when (in Excel 2013) I tried to set a name to Tab 2 or 3 I get an error.

As easy as it is, it took me 2 weeks to figure that out.  ;-(

itelly